# Вывод документа в iframe

Tags: java, html, веб-программирование, jsp, iframe

Никак не получается вывести документв в html странице в iframe. Пытаюсь сделать так:

```
<section id="info--2">
    <iframe src="serverStartup.pdf" width=400 height=500>
</section>
```

Данный пдф файл лежит в самом корне java проекта[image: Структура проекта]
Если просто прописывать путь к файлу напрямую из файловой системы, то хром блокирует содержимое и не дает вывести. Подскажите пожалуйста, как тут быть? Что я не так делаю?